# Calling C++ funtion from C to return char *

Tags: c++, mysql, c

While writing a UDF in MySQL I am stuck at calling a c++ function from c which is supposed to return `char *`. What I have tried is:

encrypt.cpp

```
string encrypt(string Data)
{
   ...
   //some encryption logic
   ...
   return encryptStr; //encryptStr is string 
}
```

To call above function from c, I am using `extern c` in the same file as:

```
extern "C" char * c_encrypt(char *bar)
{
    std::string str = encrypt(std::string(bar));
    return what_to_do_to_return_char*;
}
```

UDF.c

```
char* Encrypt_UDF( UDF_INIT* initid, UDF_ARGS* args, char* result, unsigned long* length, char* is_null, char* error )
{
    const char* arg = args->args[0];
    char * encryptData = c_encryt(arg); //calling c_encrypt()        
    return encryptData ;
}
```

So, What should I do in `c_encrypt()` to return `char *`?

Comment: Malloc some heap, copy string inside and return the malloced pointer, freeing being the responsibility of the user. Alternatively, the user can provide a pointer to pointer and the library can modify the pointed to pointer.

Comment: It's a question of ownership. Should the caller of `Encrypt_UDF` be mindful that they need to free the returned buffer? If not, do you need thread safety? Would it be a problem to impose a requirement that the whole program is linked with a C++ aware compiler/linker?

Comment: @StoryTeller: Seems like someone familiar with mySql can correctly answer this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/udf-calling.html) your function should have the following prototype:

```
extern "C" char *encrypt(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args,
      char *result, unsigned long *length,
      char *is_null, char *error);
```

Then you should use `result` and `length` parameters to "return" your string if it fits in 255 bytes (according to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/udf-return-values.html)  documentation page):

```
extern "C" char *encrypt(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args,
      char *result, unsigned long *length,
      char *is_null, char *error)
{
    std::string str = encrypt_impl(args->args[0]);
    strcpy(result, str.c_str());
    *length = str.size();
    return result;
}
```

---

In case your string doesn't always fit in 255 bytes you'll need to allocate the buffer for it yourself and more importantly **deallocate it to avoid memory leaks**. To achieve this you will have to implement additional `encrypt_init` and `encrypt_deinit` functions as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-udf.html) and define a data structure that you will use to share resource between all three functions:

```
struct EncryptData
{
    std::string encryptedStr;
};

extern "C" bool encrypt_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message)
{
    /* Use non-throwing allocation because there is no one to catch the exception */
    initid->ptr = (char *) new (std::nothrow) EncryptData();

    /* Return false if allocation failed */
    if (!initid->ptr)
        return false;
    return true;
}

extern "C" void encrypt_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid)
{
    delete (EncryptData *) initid->ptr;
}

extern "C" char *encrypt(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args,
      char *result, unsigned long *length,
      char *is_null, char *error)
{
    EncryptData *data = (EncryptData *) initid->ptr;
    data->encryptedStr = encrypt_impl(args->args[0]);

    /* Can't return c_str() here, since the return type is non-const */
    return &data->encryptedStr[0];
}
```

You could also use `initid->ptr` for the string buffer itself as suggested [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/udf-return-values.html) using `malloc/realloc/free` combination, but I think it's always better to use a `struct` or even a `class` as a general pattern to share common context between several functions.

Also note that the `encrypt` function can be called several times (for each row) and `encrypt_deinit` will be called only once (for each SQL statement), so you have to **deallocate or reuse the previous buffer** in `encrypt` before allocating a new one.

Comment: WOW!! This helped me. You are my champ today :). Thanks for docs ref. In my case I don't know how long my result will be (may be > 255 Bytes) so I will allocate own memory and return that instead.

Comment: @Amogh, I've extended my answer to include memory-management example.

Comment: Hey thanks again for extension. I have a thought on allocation of struct in `encrypt_init`. Can we call `new (std::nothrow) EncryptData()` in `encrypt()` itself and free it right there?

Comment: and as per `UDF_INIT` struct `ptr` is `char *` so e have to do type casting in encrypt_init()

Comment: @Amogh, you can't free this struct in `encrypt` because you need the string buffer to still be valid **after** `encrypt` returns.

Comment: Error in `encrypt_deinit()` and `encrypt()` as: invalid static_cast from type ‘char*’ to type ‘EncryptData*’. I changed it to `delete (EncryptData *)static_cast<char *>(initid->ptr)` and `EncryptData *data = (EncryptData *)static_cast<char *>(initid->ptr)` in it's respective method. Is it correct?

Comment: @Amogh, sorry for the purely theoretical code, I didn’t notice that ptr has char * type. You will have to replace static_cast with simple C-style cast.

Answer (score 1):

To return a char* from a C++ string in general, you would do:

```
char *c = (char*)malloc(str.size() + 1);
strcpy(c, str.c_str());
return c;
```

Note that the caller has to free the memory where char* is pointing to.

Comment: For someone who already knows what you are intending to say, the answer is quite succinct. However, for someone struggling with the concept of compiling a compatible function in C++ to be called from within a C source, the answer is a bit terse. Remember your answer is not for the person who already knows what you are doing, but for the person who doesn't. A bit more explanation will be welcomed. How, where are you defining your function? How is the C++ code compiled? How is the function accessed within C? How is the C code compiled to make use of the C++ function?